# select than grouping with all categories codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, select, categories, group

Confusing to executing this queries
`SELECT pres.db_pem, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM pres GROUP BY pres.db_pem;`
with model on codeigniter 4.

I have try with

```
public function countall()
    {   
        $this->prestasi->selectCount('*', 'cat_total');
        $this->prestasi->select("db_pem");
        $this->prestasi->groupBy('db_pem', 'ASC');
        return $this->prestasi->get()->getRowArray();
    }
```

but error happened `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as` cat_total``

Comment: check [selectCount()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder::selectCount), it should most likely look somehow similar to this: `$this->prestasi->selectCount('*', 'cat_total');`

Comment: Many thanks Vickel, i have update the script. Not showing Error now, but still not solve my problem. 
`array(2) { ["db_fail"]=> int(0) ["pendaftar"]=> array(2) { ["cat_total"]=> string(1) "2" ["db_pem"]=> string(1) "1" } }`
there should more than one category in column db_pem

Comment: `public function countall()
    { 
        $this->prestasi->select("db_pem");
        $this->prestasi->selectCount('*', 'cat_total');
        $this->prestasi->groupBy('db_pem', 'ASC');
        return $this->prestasi->get()->getResult();
    }`
I change `getRowArray()` to `getResult()` and now its show all data thanks again to @Vickel

Comment: right now (that is after your edit) this question doesn't make sense, because the error will not show anymore. The correct way would be to reverse your edit and then, if you want to, you could selfanswer your question or delete it, it doesn't help the Stack Overflow community as it is posted right now. See 
[**Can I answer my own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)